# Typescript method returns a value different than its declared return type?

Tags: typescript

I was under the impression that if declared a method with a certain return type, it would only return results of that type.  But that appears not to be the case.

If you paste the following code into the typescript playground, the result you get from
`console.log(f.count)` is `"5"`, and `console.log(paramType)` returns `string`.

It's true you have to set `noImplicit` any to `false` to set the property using the syntax `this[propName] =`  but still, it seems very odd for a language purporting to strongly typed for a method declared as number to return a string.  I would have thought I would get some kind of error at runtime when the assignment of a string to a variable declared `number`.  And also surprising that a method declared `number` is returning a `string`

What is the explanation for this behavior?

```
class foo {
    private _count: number = 0;
    get count(): number {
        return this._count;
    }
    set count(value: number) {
        this._count = value;
    }
    setValue(val: string) {
        let prop = "count"
        this[prop] = val;
    }
}

let f = new foo();
f.setValue("5")
console.log(f.count);    //"5"
let paramtype = typeof (f.count);    

console.log(paramtype)  //"string"
```

Comment: typescript gets converted to javascript while running; it is more helpful in compile-time only ie. helps you to be aware of what you are writing, what is expected out and will give compile time errors if you are trying to return invalid data type... but yes in runtime it is still javascript only

Comment: Good to know that you can't necessarily depend on the return type from a function being a variable of the declared type.

Comment: To a level, you can trust it since mostly if you are declaring string return type you will be returning a string only (a compiler will give you error if you don't)... but yes edge cases do exist

Answer (score 0):

You are, in a sense, twisting TypeScript's hands behind its back and forcing it to lose type information around this part:

```
    setValue(val: string) {
        let prop = "count"
        this[prop] = val;
    }
```

`this[prop]` is of type `any`, which means you can assign **anything** to it, including the "wrong" type for that specific property.

TypeScript does not emit runtime checks in the generated JavaScript.

So you don't get any runtime errors about this.

**TL;DR** TypeScript is only as safe and strict as you allow it to be. Here you've done the worst possible thing imaginable in TypeScript and used an implicit `any` type. And look what comes out of it! Insecure and unsafe guarantees about the API of a class.

That's why `noImplicitAny` is a flag you should always use

edit: I left out an important detail in understanding why. `prop` here is of type `string`. Accessing any property on `this` yields in `any`, because, well, how would you know what type it is if it could be *any* property? Because this is `any`, TypeScript doesn't care anymore. You can do whatever you wish with it, and that's why this can occur. To circumvent this, make `prop` the literal type `"count"` with `as const`:

```
let prop = "count" as const;
```

Or hell, just use `const` to declare it instead:

```
const prop = "count";
```

You will find that TypeScript now correctly sees `this[prop]` as `this.count` and errors out on where you wrongly assign it :)

Comment: Well, I take your point, but if I ran the joint, I really seems like it should be a compile error to assign any any typed variable to a strongly typed one.  It seems like you have to coerce it into the strong type before assignment, which at least might result in a NaN when you try to coerce the letter Q into a number.  Returning a string from a function declared number just seems wrong.

Comment: `prop` is of type `string`, right? `this[someStringValue]` is clearly `any`. You can't know what type it is since it could be any key. That's why it's `any` and that's why you can return a string from a function declared to return a number just like that. [And lastly, for kicks, try using `as const` with `prop`.](https://tsplay.dev/WzAb4m)

Comment: That's true.  Makes me nuts though. There are so few things you can count on these days!

Comment: And one of them is TypeScript, if you get used to it!